# Whats the best way I could write a recursive lambda expression to grab all the related data?

Tags: c#, recursion, linq, lambda

So, let's pretend I have table such as:

```
+-----------------+-------------------+
| Parent Id       |     Child Id      |
|-----------------|-------------------|
|1                |2                  |
|-----------------|-------------------|
|1                |3                  |
|-----------------|-------------------|
|2                |88                 |
|-----------------|-------------------|
|4                |5                  |
|-----------------|-------------------|
|5                |6                  |
|-----------------|-------------------|
|11               |12                 |
+-----------------+-------------------+
```

So, basically I want to select ParentId 1 with all the related ids which would be:
1, 2, 3, 88

Whats best way I could write lambda expression to grab all the related data?

---

I'm thinking about it just seems so messy:

```
private void GetChildCategoryIds(List<CategoryEntity> categories, ref List<long> ids)
{
    foreach(var category in categories)
    {
        ids.Add( category.ChildId );
        GetChildCategoryIds( categories.Where( ... ), ref ids);
    }
}

foreach(var o in Data.Where( w => w.ParentId == 1 ))
{
    CategoryIds.Add( o.ChildId );
    GetChildCategoryIds( categories.Where( w => w.ParentId == o.ChildId ).ToList(), ref CategoryIds );
}
```

Comment: You ask “whats best way”, but what's the way you've tried? It seems you already have a good idea of what would have to be done, but may be uncertain about a few details. Why don't you [edit] your questions to show us what you've already thought about, even if it's just a bit of pseudo-code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you absolutely want to use recursion and lambdas, something like the following should work for small data sets.

```
    public static IEnumerable<Row> GetAllChildIds(int parentId, List<Row> data)
    {
        var parents = data.Where(x => x.Id == parentId).ToList();
        return parents.Concat(parents.SelectMany(x => GetAllChildIds(x.ChildId, data)));
    }
```

Here's a full working example:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var data = new Table {Rows = new List<Row>
            {
                new Row {Id = 1, ChildId = 2},
                new Row {Id = 1, ChildId = 3},
                new Row {Id = 2, ChildId = 88},
                new Row {Id = 4, ChildId = 5},
                new Row {Id = 5, ChildId = 6},
                new Row {Id = 11, ChildId = 12},
            }};

        var ids = GetAllChildIds(1, data.Rows).ToList();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Row> GetAllChildIds(int parentId, List<Row> data)
    {
        var parents = data.Where(x => x.Id == parentId).ToList();
        return parents.Concat(parents.SelectMany(x => GetAllChildIds(x.ChildId, data)));
    }
}

class Row
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Id + " -> " + ChildId;
    }
}

class Table
{
    public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have an object...

```
public class Category
{
    public object SomeValue { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

You could get an entire tree for `categoryId` from `IEnumerable<Category> categories` like so:

```
Func<Int, IEnumerable<Category>, IEnumerable<Category>> getChildren;
getChildren = (parentId, categories) =>
    categories
        .Where(cat => cat.ParentId == parentId)
        .SelectMany(cat => getChildren(cat.Id, categories).Concat(new Category[] { cat }));

getChildren(theParentCategoryId, yourListOfCategories);
```

Haven't tested, but looks like it should work in my head...

Comment: I'm getting `use of unassigned local variable 'getChildren'`

Comment: @karlingen in the initial declaration of `getChildren` assign it to `= null;`